# Condition for field density

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Could we conclude that every ordered field (so with characteristic 0) is always dense in itself.
I know that density is a topology concept, but given the field is ordered, defining dense will be:
$$
\forall (x \lt y) \in F, \exists z \text{ such as } x<z<y
$$
Is it enough that the field is ordered to conclude it is dense in itself ?

Comment: Well, it is quite obvious. For all $x<y$ you can take $(x+y)/2$. This is well defined because $2 \neq 0$, and it is between $x,y$ using axioms of order.